# J1 visa student left due to COVID

Tags: usa, covid-19, ireland

Good evening all!

I’m looking for someone to help.
I have been in USA (Colorado) on a J1 visa working as a student on placement from Ireland back in 2018. I started in June 2018 and was due to go back home for graduation in March and return to USA to finish the placement u until June 2019. I had a rented apartment with my house mate until that date. Unfortunately when I got back home in March, COVID hit with all the restrictions resulting in my contract and flights being cancelled. Obviously for that reason I could not get back to USA and pay my rent.
I am now looking to visit the USA again ( on a tourist visa this time) would there be any problems ?
Thank you!

Comment: Did your housemate pick up your share of the rent?  Did you notify the landlord and cancel your lease?  Lot's of unanswered questions here that may or may not be relevant...

Comment: The US government doesn't care about your rent.